# Can not open a bundle signed for mac app distribution

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I'm experiencing a strange issue. When I signed my bundle with a "Mac App Distribution" certificate, I can’t launch my app (foo.app) neither my foo.pkg in local. Is it an expected behavior or I'm missing something?

Signature seems correct, if I execute codesign --verify --deep --strict --verbose=2 foo.app, I get foo.app: valid on disk
foo.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

Comment: Why can't you launch your app? What happens when you try exactly?

Comment: There is a popup with a message "Unable to open app 'xxxx'"